# Replace part of a path which has multiple occurrences into full path name by a string

Tags: batch-file, replace

I write a file batch (see below) that I run through the command prompt like this:

```
file K
```

It results in

```
"D:\android-sd*\android-sd*-windows\*\wor*space"
```

I instead need to get

```
"D:\android-sdk\android-sdk-windows\*\workspace"
```

Otherwise I need to replace "K" between "android-sdk-windows" and "workspace" by "*".
Please how to fix the batch to get this result?

```
file.bat

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set mypath="D:\android-sdk\android-sdk-windows\K\workspace"
SET mypath=!mypath:%~1=*!
echo !mypath!
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set mypath="D:\android-sdk\android-sdk-windows\K\workspace"
SET mypath=!mypath:\%~1\=\*\!
echo !mypath!
```

Comment: sometimes are things easy :) +1

Comment: I agree with you! sorry for inconvenience, I should have thought about it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

#### 1st solution: change batch code and call `file #`:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set mypath="D:\android-sdk\android-sdk-windows\#\workspace"
SET "mypath=!mypath:%~1=*!"
echo %mypath%
"D:\android-sdk\android-sdk-windows\*\workspace"
```

---

#### 2nd solution: use [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm)

```
@echo off &setlocal
set "mypath=D:\android-sdk\android-sdk-windows\K\workspace"
for /f %%i in ('echo(%mypath%^|sed s/%~1/*/') do set "mypath=%%i"
echo %mypath%
"D:\android-sdk\android-sdk-windows\*\workspace"
```

Comment: Sorry , I can't because I have to work with this kind of stuff. These are some input, I can't change them; I have to adapt my script to workaround these particular cases. thanks

Comment: `sed` is a Unix tool, I posted the link in my answer. `s/%~1/*/` simply replaces `%~1` with `*`.

Comment: so i have to install this extended tool? Sorry for this inconvience, is there no other way to do this right away by internal batch commands? Thanks